# Database for data and pictures

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I know, that I probably could try to learn everything about databases, but my way of learning is to get first push/hint from pro's and then try to figure out the rest. It narrows down the amount of things to learn at once. So far it works for me.

Long story short- my goal is to create Flutter app for iOS and Android, that can store pictures(preferably converted to PDFs- I'll do that later) and some user entered data about these pictures/PDFs.

Later the app needs to work with this entered data(sort, use, display, etc) and the app should store all of those images.
Ideally, if in future all of the data/pictures could be stored on cloud and accessed from multiple devices/app accounts.

What type of database could be most suitable for these purposes?
This is the first time for me to work with databases, so don't judge me too hard, please :) I just need a direction in which to dig.

P.S. my one goal is to build prototype-app and after it is proved that it can achieve its goals, hire pro developers to do the updates un polish everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using firebase realtime db for that (not the pdfs but it could handle those as well)...but Firestore, AWS, Azure, MongoDB on your own server, etc, etc. will all handle it. Think you need to do the reading, after all. :-)

Comment: SQLite if you only want local storage initially.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to store your images in a directory structure decided by you. Then you can store the path to these files (along with any other data) in the database.